# How do I put images next to each others

Tags: html, css

Well so, I'm kind of new to CSS and I don't understand where I'm wrong.

So I have this HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner">

        <img src="/images/LogoWhite.jpg" alt="The Mosshelter Logo" class="logo">
        <div class="left">
            <div class="min1">
                <img src="/images/1.jpg" alt="miniatura1">
            </div>
            <div class="min2">
                <img src="/images/2.jpg" alt="miniatura2">
            </div>
            <div class="min3">
                <img src="/images/3.jpg" alt="miniatura3">
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <div class="immaginedx">
                <img src="/images/30707343_763979673809675_1848895112105426944_o.jpg" alt="immaginedx">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

with this CSS (I'd like to have the 3 images one next to each other):

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
}

.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    .logo {
        width: 1000px;
        align-self: center;
    }
    .left {
        padding: 1em;
    }
    .min1 img,
    .min2 img,
    .min3 img {
        width: 100px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .right {
        .immaginedx img {
            display: none;
        }
    }
}
```

I have the three images in different divs which it should work no?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @BenAubin please don't automatically convert code to snippet without testing. the code is SASS and not CSS so it's not runnable inside a snippet

Comment: @TemaniAfif That makes sense. I assumed it wasn't scss - just an error - as there's no mention of scss in the post.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
.left {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

To:

```
.left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 1em;

  div {
    width: 33%;
  }
}
```

This will give it the correct layout properties to display the children side by side instead of underneath one another.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it but nothing happened.. I still have the 3 images one below each others..

Comment: I've updated my answer to match your specific needs.